# Update row & column in Pandas dynamically from other override Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to update a dataframe (market-data for securities in this case, tickers down the rows) based on another dataframe in which the ticker, field to be updated, and new value for the field are specified, as shown in the two tables below:

```
md = pd.DataFrame([['AAPL', 99.99, 1000000],
                            ['MSFT', 200.50, 2000000],
                            ['AMZN', 150.50, 3000000],
                            ['TSLA', 420.69, 5000000]],
                    columns=['ticker', 'close_price', 'shares'])

override = pd.DataFrame([['AAPL', 'close_price, 129.87],
                            ['TSLA', 'shares', 420000000]],
                    columns=['ticker', 'field', 'value'])
```

What is the best way to do this? I can only think to iterate over the rows in override but this seems very anti-pattern and inefficient. Its not going to be a lot of overrides, but I imagine there is proper way to perform this type of operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by pivoting your `override`, to the structure of your `md` dataset, and make sure that the `index` is 'ticker' for both:

```
override = override.pivot_table(index=['ticker'],columns=['field'],values='value')
md.set_index('ticker',inplace=True)
```

You will now have:

```
# override df
field   close_price       shares
ticker                          
AAPL         129.87          NaN
TSLA            NaN  420000000.0

# md df
        close_price   shares
ticker                      
AAPL          99.99  1000000
MSFT         200.50  2000000
AMZN         150.50  3000000
TSLA         420.69  5000000
```

Then you can `concat` both along the rows `axis=0`, perform a `groupby` on `index` (i.e. 'ticker'), and keep `last()`.

By keeping `last` you ensure that whatever comes from the override dataset will be kept, and not what was in your md dataset, hence md is overwritten:

```
res = pd.concat([md,override],axis=0)
res.groupby(res.index).last()
```

---

```
        close_price       shares
ticker                          
AAPL         129.87    1000000.0
AMZN         150.50    3000000.0
MSFT         200.50    2000000.0
TSLA         420.69  420000000.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try: it will work if the pivot of override doesn't have all the columns that are in md (i.e. if md had columns A..Z but there were only overrides for values in columns A and B?

Comment: Hi Chad. Yes, it will still work. Try it on your machine and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would first pivot `override`, then merge the result into `md` and use combine first to do the actual overriding:

```
md[['ticker']].merge(override.pivot(index='ticker',
                       columns='field', values='value'),
     left_on='ticker', right_index=True, how='left').combine_first(md)
```

It gives as expected:

```
  ticker  close_price       shares
0   AAPL       129.87    1000000.0
1   MSFT       200.50    2000000.0
2   AMZN       150.50    3000000.0
3   TSLA       420.69  420000000.0
```